In a z/OS "Signal Interface Routine"(SIR) how do you determine if cond_setup was the most recent service invoked?
In z/OS, there is a cond_setup USS service that indicates we want to receive cond_post posts.
This allows the program to indicate desire to receive posts, do some other house-keeping
and then wait for the post with cond_wait or cond_timed_wait.
However, if there is any intervening service call, the cond_wait or cond_time_wait will
fail.  The only way an intervening service call can 'creep in' is via a signal.
IBM documents this problem in several places, indicating that in the event cond_setup
has been invoked, the Signal Interface Routine (SIR) should know that and push-back any signal
(to be delivered later.)
IBM even remarks in the SIR documentation (with similar notes in the cond_setup,
cond_wait and cond_timed_wait documentation):
If the interrupt cannot be processed at this time, possibly due to
general register 13 not currently containing the address of a
program stack, or the last service called on the current thread
was cond_setup, then the queue_interrupt service request is issued.
Note that the program cannot simply have its own flag for this, because clearing the flag
before invoking cond_wait/cond_timed_wait opens a window for a signal to be delivered
which brings us immediately back to the same problem.
So - how can the SIR know that the last service called on the current thread
was cond_setup ?

Thanks!

I have read through all the various control blocks, as well as the IBM
Unix Systems Services Programming: Assembler Callable Services Reference
to try and determine how the SIR can know if cond_setup was the most recent
service invoked.
